# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at Fibonacci.main(Fibonacci.java:15)

Tags: java, arrays, types

I have to figure out a way to determine how many iterations of the Fibonacci sequence that a data type long will hold before we have bit overflow. I constantly get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at Fibonacci.main(Fibonacci.java:15).
```

I've tried to increase the length of the array, I've tried using arraylist data type (due to ignorance and not understanding my research on it, I've gone back to an empty array), and I've tried not using an array but then was told that I have to.)
 Here is my code, and I DID have a line that reduced the counter by one. I ripped it out in my attempts to debug my code. I GREATLY appreciate any/all help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] f = new long[9000];

        int k = 1;
        f[0] = 0;
        f[1] = 1;

        while (f[k] > 0) {
            f[k] = f[k - 1] + f[k - 2];
            k++;
        }


        System.out.println("The number of Fibonacci numbers a computer can compute with the data type long is " + k);
        System.out.println(k + "th Fibonacci number is " + f[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: change your title to something clearer

Comment: Your while loop tries to access array index -1 when k==1. There is not index like -1, it starts from 0

Answer (score 1):

```
while (f[k] > 0) {
    f[k] = f[k - 1] + f[k - 2];
    k++;
}
```

If `k == 1`, you try to access `f[0]` and `f[-1]`, which obviously doesn't exist, as array indexes start from `0`, not `-1`.

You should use

```
while (f[k] > 1) {
    f[k] = f[k - 1] + f[k - 2];
    k++;
}
```

Comment: You're no longer executing the code inside the while loop since f[k]=f[1]=1

Comment: @Julien Right. But note that the while loop would have resulted in an infinite loop with the code that the OP posted. Anyway, updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It would be true if there isn't an overflow when f[k]> Long.MAX_VALUE which is the purpose of the OP

Comment: @BackSlash: If there's an overflow, then f[k] will eventually wrap around and end up negative, making the condition false.  I'd suggest `while (f[k] >= f[k-1])`, as to me it shows the intent a bit better, but eh.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your while loop by the following:

```
while (f[k] > 0)
{
    f[k+1] = f[k] + f[k - 1];
    k++;
}
```

So at the first iteration, you will try to access the values stored at the index 0 and 1 which exist, and thus solving the OutOfBoundsException without modifing your algorithme since f[1] was already known.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I used that logic to get my code to work. I was trying to point to the next number in the array before it was assigned a value, so I moved the k increment above the calculation operation. Which fixed my code.